# reference types and literal types

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I looked in the standard for a definition of *reference type* but I could not find any. A naive interpretation of the *reference type* as the type of objects such as `int &` fails because according to the standard [basic.types] 10.3:

> A type is a literal type if it is: […] a reference type

But the following static assert does not compile (in MSVC2015RC):

```
    static_assert( ::std::is_literal_type< ::std::wstring & >::value, "Nope" );
```

What is the definition of a *reference type*?

Comment: *"But the following static assert does not compile:"* in which compiler?

Comment: @PiotrS. MSVC RC (just edited the question)

Comment: The code compiles fine with Visual C++ 2015 RC. You have probably forgot to include a header. Always remember to post a **complete but minimal example**, not just a snippet where *you* think the problem is (as the one who's asking, you're not qualified to decide where the problem is).

Comment: @Hector: based on your [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1566959/-std-is-literal-type-fails-for-reference-types) I've now reproduced the problem. Note that to have a valid example needs to include `<string>` header. Curiously using `int` instead of `wstring` the compilation doesn't fail.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I have updated the bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++11 Standard defines references in §8.3.2 [dcl.ref]:

> 1 In a declaration `T D` where `D` has either of the forms

```
& attribute-specifier-seqopt D1
&& attribute-specifier-seqopt D1
```

> and the type of the identifier in the declaration `T D1` is
>   “derived-declarator-type-list T,” then the type of the identifier of `D`
>   is “derived-declarator-type-list reference to `T`.” The optional
>   attribute-specifier-seq appertains to the reference type. Cv-qualified
>   references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced
>   through the use of a typedef (7.1.3) or of a template type argument
>   (14.3), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored. [...]
>
> 2 A reference type that is declared using & is called an
>   lvalue reference, and a reference type that is declared using && is
>   called an rvalue reference. Lvalue references and rvalue references
>   are distinct types. Except where explicitly noted, they are
>   semantically equivalent and commonly referred to as references.

Simply speaking, reference types are types declared as references to other types. There's much more to say about their behavior though.

Comment: I read those paragraphs but because of the bug in MSVC I thought I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

Compiles just fine, in both [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0322af5a4d3af228) and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f11b5c8b9628ddac), as it should. Your compiler has probably a bugged implementation.

Comment: Reported as [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1566959/-std-is-literal-type-fails-for-reference-types)

Comment: Seems your bug report is missing `#include <string>`